# Configuring OpenVPN on an in-house machine to act as a router for that in-house network [SOLVED]

Tags: networking, mac-osx, openvpn

I would appreciate receiving a short-list of a few good web sites that point me to how to set up the following scenario. *(You may assume that I am by-now quite familiar with OpenVPN in general.)*

I want to set up **one** always-on *(Macintosh, OS/X El Capitan,using "TunnelBlick")* computer, within an in-house network, to act as a secure router to a remote network from *any* machine within the in-house network.

Here are my thoughts ... and questions ... so far:

1. First, the Mac must be set up *(of course ...)* so that *it* can, as a client, reach and connect to the remote system. (Assume that this has already been done.)
2. The Mac's on-board firewall will need to be turned off or modified to allow *(in this case)* HTTP and HTTPS traffic to be directed to it.
3. The physical router for the in-house network must have static routing rules which direct traffic to/from the remote-side IP addresses to first be directed to this Macintosh, as a "gateway."
4. *(Now, my thinking gets fuzzy ...)* The OpenVPN client running on this machine must somehow correctly handle those "multiple connections" as they are coming to it from various in-house IP addresses. *Is* this, in fact, a special case?

Here, for your edification, is an sanitized excerpt of the present client-side `config.ovpn` file: *(You may assume that it works, because it does.)*

```
client
dev tun0
proto udp
remote 111.222.333.444 1194
pull
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
ca ca.crt
cert thisMacintosh.crt
key  thisMacintosh.key
ns-cert-type server
tls-auth ta.key 1
cipher AES-256-CBC
comp-lzo
verb 3
```

My question is *specifically* about employing this machine *as a router* which will act as a gateway for "any other machine on its local network."

Further details:

- We are communicating with a server on the Internet at "some address."  Let's say, for the sake of example, that it's `101.102.103.104`. *(Apologies to whoever's address that really is ...)*
- One machine, "on the in-house network" say at `192.168.1.20`, is to be acting as a router "the rest of the in-house network": `192.168.1.x`. It will never need to be concerned with any other internal subnet.
- The secure network on the remote side has an IP-address range of *(say)* `10.2.3.x.`
- The Mac in question currently has the necessary OpenVPN software installed, using a `.conf` similar to the above, and it *is now successfully communicating* with the Internet host.
- ... so, all I need to do are "the last few steps."  And therefore, to know what "those last few steps" *are!*

**FYI:** The "[TunnelBlick](https://www.tunnelblick.net)" software of which I speak is simply a "really nice Macintosh-friendly *wrapper"* for OpenVPN. (Similar flavors also exist for Windows and so-on.) It takes care of, for example, making sure that OpenVPN will start every time this machine is rebooted, and other otherwise-meddlesome details. But it simply *hosts* the otherwise-normal OpenVPN process which handles the actual communication. Therefore, I believe that my questionings are "essentially generic to any OS," and that "my answer must be terribly easy."

You don't need to answer "in terms of `iptables`," nor in terms of the actual equivalent commands that a Macintosh uses. *(Unless you -want- to "speak Mac to me.")* If you'll just help me grok **what** needs to be done, I can figure out what steps to take to persuade a Macintosh and the local hardware-router to do it.

Pages I have recently studied, and am continuing to study *(especially the second one)*

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35352228/route-traffic-from-internal-network-eth1-through-openvpn-tun0
- https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/RoutedLans

*(Based on the second page, I have a now-murky gut feeling that what I need to do "has something to do with **`iroute`** ... but that I could also be totally mistaken about that." (Does this client-machine "have the rest of the in-house network to which it belongs 'behind it?'" Or, "is it not-relevant (i.e. wrong), since all other machines that will be talking through this machine "are right here?") Ooh, so confused. That's why I'm now asking you kind folks!)*

(When you post an answer, please also post a *comment* because I can *see* the presence of comments but I have not yet discovered how to get a list of "my recent questions ...")

Comment: "router for the in-house network must have static routing rules which direct traffic to/from the remote-side IP addresses to first be directed to this Macintosh".  No--all devices in the house should have the forwarding Mac as their default gateway; you don't want them to keep the old router as their gateway and then bounce back to the Mac.  Your DHCP server (assuming thats how you manage local addresses) should be pushing the Mac's IP as the default router on your network.

Comment: No, this Mac should **not** be "the default router for this network." It should be the gateway *only* for traffic destined to/from `10.2.3.x` and none other. I definitely do not 100% of the network traffic to become directed to and through this machine!

Comment: Ah--in that case, you should push a static route 10.2.3.x/24 via ${MAC_IP_ADDR} to all the end nodes.  You still probably don't want traffic to bounce through your router if its not necessary.  Many SOHO grade router products will not perform "one-armed routing."

Comment: I think that I can accomplish this step by editing the configuration of the hardware router which services this subnet.  They have a pretty sophisticated router, not just something that was bought at a convenience store. I know that there needs to (somehow, somewhere) be a routing-rule that directs `10.2.3.x` through a gateway at `192.168.1.20`. My question is really very-specifically directed at the proper *OpenVPN-client configuration,* so that it *does* act as a router when traffic from other `192.168.1.x` nodes is being sent to it as a gateway.

Comment: To clarify: "the traffic that this OpenVPN client is to handle is not coming just from the machine that's running the client, but from any other machine in the `192.168.1.x` subnet.  And I'm specifically focusing on how to tell *OpenVPN* that." I'm confident that, with a sledgehammer and a little persuading **;-)** I can get the hardware router to deliver the packets to it.  (And of course I'm thinking about the entire round-trip, to make sure that the returned packets get back home.) I want to confirm OpenVPN settings, and to confirm what the hardware router's rules must be.

Comment: Mike, there is no specific openVPN configuration needed for it to act as a router.  The *host machine* needs to be told to act as a router, by enabling ip forwarding / gateway mode / etc.  The name/term varies by OS.  On the mac it's probably a sysctl setting telling it that it should act as a gateway.  When that is set, if the routes are in place, it will "just work."

Comment: I'd love for you to flesh that out as an Answer.  (Doesn't need to drill down to "exactly what command to use 'on a Mac'," or "what the terminology is 'on a Mac,'" because clearly this question is generic to OpenVPN anywhere.) ### Be sure I understand *exactly* what you mean by "the host machine." (Cite the dummy IP-addresses I included in my OP.  I invented an address or range for each one.)  "The rules are in place? ... *exactly what* rules do you mean?" And so on.  Thanks in advance. (I've been (over-)thinking about this too much and for too long.)

Comment: *Meh...* "The routes," you said, not "the rules" ... Me bad.

Answer (score 0):

I see that this very-old question of mine never actually got an "answer."  So, I'll provide a brief one now.

- It is necessary for the routers at both sides to know to `route` traffic bound for the other-side network, *and* the IP-address range used by OpenVPN itself, to the computer that is running the OpenVPN software.  Firewall rules everywhere must not block this.
- The OpenVPN configuration must also contain `iroute` directives to tell it about the address-ranges that exist *behind* each remote.  This is needed even when there is only one such remote.

Very nice write-up:  https://backreference.org/2009/11/15/openvpn-and-iroute/

This worked very well for a time, until the client realized that their very-expensive network infrastructure natively supported ipSEC-style VPN, as did VMWare on the cloud side.  So, they switched to this technology as the primary conduit to connect their home office to the cloud systems, and it proved to be a nice "set it and forget it" proposition for them.  They continue to use OpenVPN to support "road warriors" with digital certificates and `tls-auth`.